# entity framework -FireBase- FileStream the file cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, entity

I want to upload Entity Framework Code First (.mdf file) to FireBase.

`var stream = new FileStream (FBS_Directory + @ "\ DB.mdf", FileMode.Open);`

I want to open the file and send it to FireBase, but I get the error "The file cannot be accessed because the process is being used by another process." What do you suggest for this?
how can i close the database connection

Answer (score 0):

You must to close the database connection before you open it for another process.
Use "using" to dispose and close the connection:

```
using (var context = new EFContext(...)
{
   ...
}
```

I hope this help you.